# Minimising client processing - c socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am working on a client/server model based on Berkeley sockets and have almost finished but I'm stuck with a way to know that all of the data has been received whilst minimising the processing being executed on the client side.

The client I am working with has very little memory and battery and is to be deployed in remote conditions. This means that wherever possible I am trying to avoid processing (and therefore battery loss) on the client side. The following conditions on the client are outside of my control:

- The client sends its data 1056 bytes at a time until it has ran out of data to send *(I have no idea where the number 1056 came from but if you think that you know I would be very interested)*
- The client is very unpredictable in when it will send the data *(it is attached to a wild animal and sends data determined by connection strength and battery life)*
- The client has an unknown amount of data to send at any given time
- The data is transmitted though a GRSM enabled phone tag *(Not sure that this is relevant but I'm assuming that extra information could only help)*
- *(I am emulating the data I am expecting to receive from the client through localhost, if it seems to work I will ask the company where I am interning to invest in a static ip address to allow "real" tcp transfers, if it doesn't I won't. I don't think this is relevant but, again,  I would rather provide too much information than too little)*

At the moment I am using a while loop and incrementing the number of bytes received in order to "recv()" each of the 1056 byte sections. My problem is that the server needs to receive an unknown number of these. To me, the most obvious solutions are to send the number of sections to be received in an initial header from the client or to mark the last section being sent in some way. However, both of these approaches would require processing on the client side, I was wondering if there was a way to check whether the client has closed its socket from the server side? Or even whether something like closing the connection from the server after a pre-determined period of time without information from the client would be feasible? If these aren't possible then I would love to hear any other suggestions.

TLDR: What condition can I use here to **minimise client-side processing**?

```
while(!(/* Client has ran out of data to send*/)) {
    receive1056Section();
}
```

*Also, I know that it is bad practise to make a stackOverflow account and immediately ask a question, I didn't know what else to do, I'm sorry. Please don't hesitate to be mean if I've missed something very obvious.*

Comment: If you've got a connection-oriented transmission (TCP), you don't care about the size of the packets (which means your library *does* care). If you need to keep processing to a minimum, consider using UDP.

Comment: Not sure I understand?  Why would implementing a protocol require more processes?   Given the err... 'unstable' nature of the comms, I wonder if TCP is the best protocol?  Small UDP packets may be better?  Does it matter if some data gets lost?

Comment: I don't think that I can use UDP as the data being transferred is satellite co-ordinates tracking the animals, my understanding is that UDP doesn't guarantee the order of transmission, which would be an issue. Also, I'm only an intern and was told to do tcp, they may have other reasons for wanting a working tcp server that they haven't told me.

Comment: I have asked whether UDP would be a better alternative and the issue with UDP is that there is no guarantee that the packet actually reaches the server.  Apparently, due to the animals often being underwater or in places with very limited GRSM coverage it is very important to confirm that the data has in fact reached the server to avoid data being lost.

Comment: That'sa lot of bytes for GPS coords and maybe a device/animal ID:(   Anyway, if you're stuck with TCP, I suggest keeping comms in self-contained application-protocol units that can be parsed and processed independently of any socket open/close.  Specific designs to reduce overall power consumption at the client would require a lot more information, and require a lot mor work, than SO can reasonably be expected to provide.

Comment: Also 'client I am working with has very little memory', well, then you have a problem.  If the GPRS has no service, you will quickly run out of data storage and so lose it anyway:(

Comment: How does the use of processes equate to battery loss? I've never heard that correlation before. If you are running something on the CPU then sure battery will be consumed. But how is that specific to **processes**? Or do you mean **processing**?

Comment: @MartinJames I don't know the exact specifications of the tags that I'm working with. Some weigh less than a gram, so I was told to do "everything possible" to avoid wasting battery. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @AlanAu I wasn't aware of the difference, thank you.

Comment: Uh, if the network connection is lost, `TCP` won't magically successfully transmit the data either.

Comment: @EOF But if the client doesn't receive confirmation that the data has been received then it will know to resend the data next time it has connection - with UDP the only way to (try to) avoid all data losses would be to resend all of its data each time.

Comment: So, if the TCP-stream resends the data later, it'd better have a timestamp in there, or it'll be rather confusing. And if you've got a timestamp in every coordinate-packet, you don't need in-sequence delivery any more.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to check whether the client has closed its socket from the server side? Yes, make use of select, poll method and find the number of bytes read by read call; if read is zero then we confirm that client closed the connection

Comment: @EOF unfortunately, the guy who originally programmed the tag is on holiday but my current understanding is that there is a buffer of data in memory on the tag and a pointer. Each time a 1056 byte section is sent and confirmed to have been received by the server the pointer is then incremented, if there is no confirmation then it will reattempt to send that 1056 byte section.

Comment: I would recommend you to go thru event handling like poll, select for handling socket programming;  It is always recommend to send the amount of data you are planning to send before sending the actual data in that way the other end keeps the data buffer ready;

Comment: My point is that you *need* a timestamp when sending via TCP, because if it retries sending when reestablishing network connection, it may send multiple coordinates *at the same time*, which is impossible, assuming the monitored animal moves at finite velocities.

Comment: @Viswesn Sre you saying that ((numBytes = recv(...)) == 0) would be the condition that I'm looking for? My understanding (from here: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select) of select() is that it is to allow multiple clients to connect at the same time, at the moment I'm doing that with forking, please could you explain the use of select?

Comment: @EOF I understand what you mean. The co-ordinates aren't sent as the data is collected. They are sent once per day, once per week ,every 5th time a marine mammal surfaces etc. So there will be a build-up of data of the animal's previous locations over the last week or so with a timestamp for each co-ordinate. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @MichaelRadigan: Ok, so if each coordinate has an associated timestamp, why do you need the ordering guarantees TCP provides? The timestamps should easily allow restoring the order even is they are transmitted by UDP.

Comment: @EOF I was wrong, I didn't need the ordering from tcp. I needed the guarantee of receipt to avoid having to resend all of the data each time. For example, if I send yesterday's co-ordinates using tcp then I know that they have been received. If I send yesterday's co-ordinates using UDP I will have to send them again today, tomorrow and the day after in case it wasn't received.

Comment: @MichaelRadigan: But TCP gives *much more* guarantees than you need. You only need an acknowledgement of correct reception form the recipient, which shouldn't be difficult to implement in UDP, for *much less* overhead than full TCP

Comment: @EOF The clients use GRSM phone tags, wouldn't their ip being allocated dynamically make connection from the server to the client via UDP (for confirmation of full receipt) very difficult?

Comment: @MichaelRadigan: UDP packets sill contain an IP-packet, including source address, so the server can reply to a UDP-packet sent by a client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for how to do the interaction:

**The client:**

Client connects to server via tcp.

Client sends chunks of data until all data has been sent. Flush the send buffer after each chunk.

When it is done the client issues a `shutdown` on the socket, `sleep`s for a couple of seconds and then closes the connection.

The client then sleeps until the next transmission. If the transmission was unsuccessful, the sleep time should be shorter to prevent unsent data to overflow the avaiable memory.

If the client is unable to connect for an extended period of time, you would have to discard data that doesn't fit in the memory.

I am assuming that `sleep` reduces power consumption.

**The server:**

The server programcan be single-threaded unless you need massive scalability. It is listening for incoming connections on the agreed port.

Whenever a client connects, a new socket is created.

Use `select()` to see which sockets has data (don't forget to include the listening socket!), and non-blocking reads to read from the sockets.

When you get the appropriate error (no more data to read and the other side has `shutdown` it's side of the connection), then you can close that socket.

This should work fine up to a couple of thousand *simultaneous* connections.

[Example that handles many of the difficulties of implementing a server](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/selectserver.c)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The clients have a VERY basic operating system,  I'm not sure how I would go about writing a shutdown function, is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GRSM. In fact I've never even heard of it. If the client cannot use tcp sockets, then you should consider retagging the question to more appropriate (telephony) tags.

Comment: If the client doesn't need to read from the socket you can just use `close` and skip the `shutdown`. The `shutdown` is used to signal that you are done sending data, but that you may still want to read a reply.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the issue with using GRSM is the same as though you were using something without a static ip address. To send information from the server to a client is still tcp based but what ip adress do you use to set up the connection? Once the client has set up the connection, the transfer can be done normally. Does that makes it off topic? The issue with shutdown isn't anything to do with GRSM, shutdown it's a function defined by the OS (sysvinit in the linux kernel). The client's OS doesn't have this and I would have to write this myself.  The issue is that I don't know how.

Comment: In that case your answer is perfect, I'll accept it. Thank you very much for your help!